# Using .siblings() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this html code:

```
<div class="mws-form-item prova">
   <select class="target" id="select1">
      <option value="noselected" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
  </select>
  <select class="target">
      <option value="noselected" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
  </select>
  <select class="target">
      <option value="noselected" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
      <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" style="width: 35px" min="1" max="99" value="1">
</div>
```

and the jQuery code:

```
 $(document).on('change', '.prova> .target', function () { //line 1
    ...
    $( "select" ).each(function( index ) {
        $(this).children().each(function () {
            if (this.innerHTML === selectedValue) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });
    ...
});
```

that removes all the childrens of the `<select>` that match the if condition.
As said, in this way all the `<select>` will be affected, instead I want that this select couldn't be affected. So I was thinking to use `.siblings()` in this way:

```
 $(document).on('change', '.myclass > .target', function () { //line 1
    ...
    $(this).siblings().each(function( index ) {
        $(this).childrens().each(function () {
            if (this.innerHTML === selectedValue) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });
    ...
});
```

But this does not work!

And then: is there another way for referring to all select except a specific one?

Comment: *"But this does not work!"* What happens?

Comment: The elements are not removed

Comment: Well, there is no `childrens()` method for starters ?

Comment: The issue could be $(this).children()

Comment: Adeneo spotted the problem. `$(this).childrens()` should be `$(this).children()`. `$(this).siblings()` should work without issue. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) to be able to figure out such problems yourself.

Comment: @Marcus: Why did you fix the code? The typo was probably the OPs problem. Or are you certain that it wasn't?

Comment: @FelixKling Oh, my bad. I fixed the formatting and just copy pasted the code from his first example since I thought them to be the same. I'll change it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that your `change` event fires on the `<select>` elements and remove the one that triggered the event. Modify your first snippet like this:

```
$( "select" ).not(this).each(...)
```

That said, IMHO it is quite confusing to refer to the `<select>` elements first with their class (`> .target`) and then with their element name -- why don't you standardize?

Comment: This helps me! thank you! Yes, I need to standardize the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('change', '.mws-form-item > .target', function () {
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    $(this).siblings('select').children().filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == selectedValue;
    }).remove();
});
```

Comment: I have followed the suggestion of @Jon, but I don't understand why your code does not work in my page

Answer (score -2):

Its probably because you can't use the

```
this
```

inside functions like that. Its a namespacing issue.

Try this

```
$(document).on('change', '.myclass > .target', function () { //line 1
...
var self = $(this)
$(this).siblings().each(function( index ) 
        self.children().each(function () {
          //HERE THIS IS REFERING TO OPTIONS, RIGHT?
          if (this.innerHTML === selectedValue) {
        self.remove();
          }
        });   
    });
 ...
});
```

Note I've changed "childrens to children" also

Comment: *"Its a namespacing issue."* There is nothing related to namespaces in the code. And of course you can use `this` in a function, as long as you know what it refers to. The OPs code is using `this` correctly. Your code on the other hand does not make sense. For each sibling you are iterating over the changed elements children (i.e. you are iterating over the same option elements multiple times). If the condition is true (which it will always be, because the selected value is one of the options), you are removing the select box.